# Unreal Engine 4.24: Plugin 'AndroidPermission' failed to load because module 'AndroidPermission' could not found

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, unreal-engine4, carla

I am preparing a project about self-driving vehicles and I will work on the Carla simulator. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and installed Unreal Engine version 4.24. I've done the steps in the Carla document one by one, but when running the UE4Editor, I get the AndroidPermission not found error. Even though I disabled this on the uplugin file of it, still the same problem persists. How can I solve this problem? Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set `"EnabledByDefault": false` on `/Engine/Plugins/Online/Android/OnlineSubsystemGooglePlay/OnlineSubsystemGooglePlay.uplugin` because the plugin OnlineSubsystemGooglePlay requires AndroidPermission.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run the Unreal Editor? Or are you calling `make launch` to start CARLA?

In the first case, set `"EnabledByDefault": false` and `"Installed": true` in `/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/AndroidPermission/AndroidPermission.uplugin`. I assume that the Installed attribute is set to False on your end.

In the second case, try to start CARLA in Visual Studio Code by selecting the launch configuration `CarlaUE4Editor(Development)`. For this you need to open the workspace inside `/Unreal/CarlaUE4/CarlaUE4.code-workspace`.

[image: Debug tab in Visual Studio Code]